# Computer has slowed down A LOT!

Tags: 16.04

Computer out of nowhere has slowed down quite a bit. It appears to be Chrome that is causing the issues. At least according to "top"

Used dmesg to watch it for a few moments and no errors. I watched top for a few momrents while typing this and it goes up to above 60% CPU usage for chome. Is this a known issue? Please help. I use this computer for research and it is essentially unusable as is.

Running Ubuntu 16.04LTS with Celeron N2830. I understand it is a cheaper computer but when i first installed the distro it was running beautifully.

Also have 4 gb of RAM

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How much swap? How many tabs open in Chrome? How many extensions in Chrome?

Comment: 8GB of swap. I purposely made it more than RAM. Just the one tab open in Chrome. And just adblock running. Going to run apt-get dist-upgrade. When I just restarted I got an error related to Xorg. There are some updates coming through for Xorg so I am going to see if that helps any.

Comment: Have you installed any Chrome plug-ins or extensions? Have you tried disabling all Chrome extensions and plug-ins?

Answer (score 0):

Complete re-write... from the comments...

re: SMART says pre-fail

on Raw Read Error Rate, Reallocated sector ct, and Seek Error rate.

Backup your data and replace the HDD.

Comment: Didn't seem to help any. Going to check HDD.

Comment: In `terminal` type `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` look for disk errors

Comment: Nothing. I might try a fresh install. I really hate to do that though

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it's any faster... keeping in mind the medium.

Comment: Downloading ISO now. Will let you know once I get it downloaded and running in Live mode

Comment: So after trying the live boot it does seem to perform better. After this i went into installed on HDD. I am becoming suspicious of the drive. I go into gsmartcontrol and three of the attributes are pre-failure. So does this mean that the drive is failing?

Comment: What three attributes are they? Show me a screenshot. Is your disk known as sda, or something else? Do `sudo fdisk -l` to see. Is it SSD or HDD? Did you reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: ps: if your drive is a SSD, tell me the make/model.

Comment: Raw Read Error Rate, Reallocated sector ct, and Seek Error rate. It is sda and boot partition is sda1, swap is sda2, main partition is sda3. It is a traditional drive. I reinstalled and it is still running slow. As I said it slowed down out of nowhere so I am thinking it is HDD related. Could it be that it is some other hardware though?

Comment: Sounds like your HDD is bad.

Comment: Chrome does a lot of writing to the HD, usually every couple of seconds. If your HD is flaky, that could compound your problem. It could also push the drive over the edge. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/DrM9vRQ6e_w